# Data request for Azure Resource usage api failed

Tags: azure, azure-billing-api

Using Resource usage Api to calculate resource consumption cost.
Sometimes exception occurred as

> "The data requested has not yet been processed. Please try again in 5
>   minutes"

Code used:

```
string usageUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", "https://management.azure.com","subscriptions", subscriptionId, "providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=" + startDate + "T09%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&reportedEndTime=" + endDate + "T" + endTime + "%3a00%3a00%2b00%3a00&aggregationGranularity=Hourly&showDetails=true");

HttpWebRequest usageRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(usageUrl);

usageRequest.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + accessToken);

usageRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

HttpWebResponse responses = (HttpWebResponse)usageRequest.GetResponse();

Stream receiveStreams = responses.GetResponseStream();

StreamReader readStreams = new StreamReader(receiveStreams, Encoding.UTF8);

var usageResponse = readStreams.ReadToEnd();
```

> Inputs:
>
> startDate - 2017-01-07,
>
> endDate   - 2017-01-10,
>
> endTime   - 09(hour).
>
> Current UTC date - 2017-01-10(yyyy-MM-dd)
>
> Current UTC time - 09:15:25(hh:mm:ss)

No problems with the format. This code works fine if endTime is passed as "08".